# Erro ao invocar método 'com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.registerCallback' on a null object reference

Tags: android

Sempre que inicializo a aplicção aparece este erro:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.registerCallback(com.facebook.CallbackManager, com.facebook.FacebookCallback)' on a null object reference.

Segue parte do código:

```
 login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
```

Comment: Provavelmente é Java em Android, se for o caso provavelmente vc adicionou o código ANTES de `setContentView`, logo os elementos como widgets ainda não estão prontos, mas não tenho poderes mediúnicos, não consigo saber como esta o seu código no momento, então não tenho como ajudar além disto, a unica maneira de ter certeza é se vc seguir as regras do site e criar sempre um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Obrigado Guiherme me ajudou demais !!!!

Comment: Blz murilo, formulei como resposta, se achar que esta OK marque-a como correta, grato!

Answer (score 1):

O erro provavelmente indica que os elementos não estão prontos, no caso o widget `com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` ao qual tentou registrar o callback

Em Android os elementos só estarão disponiveis após o `setContentView`, se tentar registrar eventos em widgets antes irá causar falhas, você deve ter feito algo como:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    }
});

...

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

E o correto deve ser:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
       ...
    }
});
```